# MFC: Can we extend the CEdit control class behaviour present in CEditView

Tags: c++, mfc

I read few basics about MFC and I am trying to implement simple editor using `CEditView`. Please correct if my current understanding is wrong.

`CEditView` is just a view, physically there won't be any control placed in it.

1. `CEditView` is just the area, where user can see and enter the text.
2. Explicitly no need to place any `CEdit` control on to the view (like
   we put `CEdit` control on the `CDialogView`).
3. `CEdit` control is just a member of `CEditView.(GetEditCtrl())`.

Currently `CEdit` provides so many edit related features. If I want to extend that `CEdit` member class, is it possible to do it? It's something like:

```
Class CMyEdit : public CEdit
```

From MSDN:

> You construct a `CEdit` object in two steps. First, call the `CEdit`
>   constructor and then call Create, which creates the Windows edit
>   control and attaches it to the `CEdit` object.

I create dummy constructor:

```
CMyEdit::CMyEdit
{

}
```

After that I called `Create`:

```
virtual BOOL Create(
    DWORD dwStyle,  
    const RECT& rect,  
    CWnd* pParentWnd,  
    UINT nID);

   //Here I have given dummy CRect and dummy Control ID that is 1;
   myEdit->Create(ES_MULTILINE | WS_CHILD | 
                  WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | 
                  WS_BORDER,CRect(10, 10, 100, 100), this, 1);
```

If I create and when I run the program, `CEdit` control is coming onto the `CEditView`. But I don't want that physical control onto the `CEditView`.

Do we need to create method here? Not sure how to extend this `CEdit` class behaviour without creating the control.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ceditview-class) explicitly calls out where you can customize the behavior of the `CEditView` class. As written, this question is almost impossible to answer, since we have no idea, what aspect of the behavior you are trying to modify.

Comment: I am using MDI template not the dialog based window. Actually I need to implement something like Syntax coloring for my editor. So far, I developed my editor using existing Coledocument/CEditViw/CEdit capabilities..Here I need to use different colors based on keywords.Just for color, I don't want to reimplement  this using CRichEditView/CRichEdit/CRichEditDoc

Comment: [Edit controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/edit-controls) do not support formatting. You need to find a different solution.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use an existing syntax highlighter like Scintilla for whom  [MFC wrapper classes](https://github.com/wingkinl/ScintillaWrapper) exist.

Answer (score 1):

1. `CEditView` is a `CEdit` as a view, In fact In a `CEdit` and in a `CEditView` there is a normal Windows API Edit control inside. It is a little trick, that the MFC is using. It creates a simple Edit control, (so there is one window handle), but you can treat this handle via a `CView` pointer AND a `CEdit` pointer. When you look into the code, you see that `GetEditCtrl` just casts the this pointer.
2. When you create a View with a `CEditView` you have always a `CEdit`/`Edit control` inside... you can't change that.
3. Sure that you get a new edit control over a `CEditView` if you create an additional control inside of it.
4. If you can't create a `CMyEditView` derived from `CView` with a `CMyEdit` inside of it (using the full view).

The easiest way would just be to extend a `CEditView` to a `CMyEditView`...

Comment: your 4th point is little intresting..Can you explain me clearly? I have a child edit view class which is derived from CEditview, which has a member variable CMyEdit, which is the derived from CEdit class

Comment: I change my mind. It is easier to create your own CView class and create a CMyEdit inside this. This will create two visible windows but it works. The internal window covers the complete CView area...

Comment: The 4th bullet point still suggests that it were possible to exchange a `CEditView`'s enclosed `CEdit` control. This is simply not supported. And if it were, the customized `CMyEdit` control still wouldn't support formatting in a way the OP is seeking to implement.

Comment: @IInspectable you are right. This isn't possible. I change the text!

Answer (score -1):

It is not very clear what behavior you are trying to modify but looks like you are aware that in MFC you can create your own custom control. You can override the methods of your CEdit in the custom control class CMyEdit like OnPaint() etc. and achieve the same. You should go through with the tutorial which mentioned in details about the custom controls and then you will get to know what all methods you need to override in your custom controls.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked. You cannot replace the `CEdit` control contained within a `CEditView` with your custom `CEdit` implementation. It is an answer to a different question, that doesn't apply here.